# SweetAlert - how to disable auto-focus on initial opening?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am using [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) and I have custom buttons like this example:

```
swal("A wild Pikachu appeared! What do you want to do?", {
  buttons: {
    cancel: "Run away!",
    catch: {
      text: "Throw Pokéball!",
      value: "catch",
    },
    defeat: true,
  },
  onOpen: function() { console.log("Test") } // this doesn't work
})
.then((value) => { ... });
```

However, on initial opening, it's focusing to the last button. Is there a way to cancel this auto-focus completely so on initial opening, it doesn't focus on any button?

Comment: The `onOpen` event not available on SweetAlert. You could use SweetAlert2 instead https://sweetalert2.github.io

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that after everything was done in the project :(. Would everything work same way if I just change the npm package? Or is swal2 a complete rewrite?

Comment: They are different packages with different APIs.

Comment: This publication served me as it provides a clear example [Show SweetAlert2 over Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806448/show-sweetalert2-over-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 5):

As already suggested in comments, [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) is more flexible solution, I recommend using it.

With `didOpen` parameter and `getConfirmButton()` method you can achieve the desired behavior:

```js
Swal.fire({
  input: 'text',
  inputPlaceholder: 'I will not be autofocuses',
  didOpen: () => Swal.getConfirmButton().focus()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```